# insert de um formulario com while

Tags: php, html, mysql

ola eu tenho este formulário que se multiplica de acordo com o cadastro de app para o usuario,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

.

veja o resultado graficamente,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como eu faço para inserir no banco de dados sendo que eu posso ter um usuário com ate 7 registro distintos ou mais? atualmente estou fazendo meio q manual mas com registros q não era para ser inserido

```html
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['nivel_acesso_id'] != '2') { //verifica se existe um usuario logado.
    
}
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "teste"); 

$brf1 = $_POST['brf1'];
$brf2 = $_POST['brf2'];
$brf3 = $_POST['brf3'];
$brf4 = $_POST['brf4'];
$brf5 = $_POST['brf5'];
$brf6 = $_POST['brf6'];
$brf7 = $_POST['brf7'];

$app1 = '1';
$app2 = '2';
$app3 = '3';
$app4 = '4';
$app5 = '5';
$app6 = '6';
$app7 = '7';
$iduser = $_SESSION['id'];



// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO events (id_nome, brfinal, aplicativo)
VALUES ('$iduser', '$brf1', '$app1');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO events (id_nome, brfinal, aplicativo)
VALUES ('$iduser', '$brf2', '$app2');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO events (id_nome, brfinal, aplicativo)
VALUES ('$iduser', '$brf3', '$app3')";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO events (id_nome, brfinal, aplicativo)
VALUES ('$iduser', '$brf4', '$app4')";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO events (id_nome, brfinal, aplicativo)
VALUES ('$iduser', '$brf5', '$app5')";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO events (id_nome, brfinal, aplicativo)
VALUES ('$iduser', '$brf6', '$app6')";

if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos para logar-s333e.'); history.back();</script>";
    header("Location: calendar.php");
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos para logar-s111e.'); history.back();</script>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Passa um `JSON` contendo arrays contendo os dados dos `<forms>`.

Comment: Primeiramente, evite usar imagens para códigos, afinal se formos fazer algo para ajudar, não vamos digitar o que vc ja poderia ter colocado digitado aqui pra nós. Segundo que preciso saber como vc envia os dados para o PHP, através do submit padrão do `<form>` ou usando JS?

Comment: ok desculpa mas tudo para min aqui é novo mas com relação ao submit é o padrao do form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver o problema depois de um tempo analisando fica aqui um muito obrigado por tudo que fizeram para mim.

a forma que eu consegui resolver foi alterando o input do formulário app tirando o disabled que não passa valor e colocando o readonly que bloqueia do mesmo jeito e passa valores a outra foi alterando a $row['idnome'] que passava apenas o nome e não a id o resto foi o que o leo passou como exemplo.

```html
label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Aplicativo</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <?php echo $row['idnome'];?>
                          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="app[]" id="app"  value="<?php echo $row['idapp'];?>" readonly>

                      </div>
```

e o php ficou assim

```html
include_once("conexao.php");

$qtd_insert = count($_POST['brf']);


for($i = 0; $i <$qtd_insert; $i++) {
    $app = $_POST['app'][$i];
    $brf = $_POST['brf'][$i];
    
    

   $query = "INSERT INTO events(id_nome, brfinal, aplicativo) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$brf', '$app')";
    if(!$conn->query($query) === true) {
     die("<script>alert('Erro na inserção dos dados!!!');</script>: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error);
     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia cara, o que você pode fazer é o seguinte. Primeiramente em seu `FORM` você vai colocar no final de cada `name` dos inputs um `[]` para que isso se torne uma espécie de `array` quando você enviar os dados para o PHP. Com isso, você não precisa mais identificar o ID de cada linha como está fazendo. Pela parte do PHP, é bem simples o que você irá fazer, basicamente você vai rodar um `INSERT` dentro de um `foreach` ou um `for` onde você vai passar por parâmetro a quantidade de `id`que voce tinha no FORM como quantidade de vezes que ele terá que rodar o INSERT no Banco. Ficará mais ou menos assim:

Seus input's onde eu só copiei a DIV com os que estavam dentro, apenas troque o nome destes no seu HTML:

```
    <div class="com-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="app[]">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="brinicial[]">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="count[]">
        <input type="text" name="brf[]">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="naojogou[]">
    </div>
```

Seu script no PHP:

```
<?php
$id = $connect->insert_id; 
$qtd_insert = sizeof($_POST['app']);

for($i = 0; $i <$qtd_insert; $i++) {
    $app = $_POST['app'][$i];
    $count = $_POST['count'][$i];
    $brf = $_POST['brf'][$i];
    $checkbox = isset($_POST['naojogou'][$i]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO events(id_nome, brfinal, aplicativo) VALUES ('$id', '$brf', '$app')";
    if(!$connect->query($query) === true) {
        die("Erro na inserção dos dados: " . $query . "<br>" . $connect->error)
    }
}
?>
```

Contudo, como eu não tinha seu HTML, fiquei meio confuso de quais campos você está inserindo no BD, caso não seja estes que coloquei na query, apenas substitua pelas outras variáveis ali. Em questão do checkbox, você consegue verificar se um checkbox está marcado ou não através do `isset`, ele faz uma espécie de verificação onde caso o checkbox estiver marcado, ele existe, caso contrário ele não existe, e com isso ele consegue pegar ou não o valor do mesmo.

Comment: muito obrigado mas os únicos campos q vai para o db são o app e o brf e o id do usuário testando com o exemplo q deu e muito obrigado por tudo.

Comment: Caso a resposta satisfaça sua questão, não se esqueça de marcar como " Corretar " e marcar um ponto clicando na setinha para cima rs.

Comment: boa tarde fiz as alterações só que ele insere apenas o do 1º imput o da repetição ele não mostra porem quando dou um print_r do brf[] ele mostra Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 120 ). lembrando que eu so quero colocar no inserir no banco de dados os valores do brf o id do usuario e o app q ele esta cadastrado

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa entender o funcionamento do recebimento de dados dos formulários pelo `PHP`, quando se trata de formulários com informações repetidas como é o seu caso, você tem outra opção para facilitar o tratamento desses dados que ficaria assim:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    <input type="text" name="nome_do_input_1[]">
    <input type="text" name="nome_do_input_2[]">
}
```

> **Nota:** perceba que isso é um exemplo  de como você pode fazer, adicionando seu código e os valores como desejar, desde que o nome do `<input>` seja acompanhado de `[]`, pois assim o `PHP` vai compreender que esse input é um `array`.

No `PHP` você vai receber um `array` assim:

```
array (size=3)
  'nome_do_input_1' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'input 1' (length=7)
      1 => string 'input 1 de novo' (length=15)
  'nome_do_input_2' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'input 2' (length=7)
      1 => string 'input 2 de novo' (length=15)
```

Portanto basta tratar os dados como `arrays` que são usando laços de repetição para fazer os tratamentos de entrada, lembrando que cada chave numérica dos arrays são respectivamente de cada `app`, exemplo: toda chave `0` é do primeiro `app`, toda chave `1` é do segunddo, etc.

Comment: boa tarde Wees como eu tenho muito pouco conhecimento eu não sei como inserir no DB os array do brf[] que com o print_r($_POST) mostra este resultado Array ( [count] => 2 [brf] => Array ( [0] => 50 q refere ao 1º form [1] => 120 que se ref a ao 2º form e dependendo do USER ele pode ter ate 10 ou mais form) )  já a os app são trazido no DB onde estão cadastrado aqle USER a poder jogar com o exemplo do leo eu consegui inserir o 1º resultado o problema agora e o do segundo em diante pois o APP cadastrado não vem do método post e sim do DB q o user ta cadastrado.